# Kmeans obtener tabla de cada cluster

Tags: r

Necesito caracterizar los individuos de mi tabla, aplicando Kmeans y no pude lograr una tabla con todos los valores de las variables para un cluster determinado, me podría orientar cómo hacer esto???.
Yo hice lo siguiente:

```
library(readxl)
IngresantesN <- read_excel("D:/PRUEBAS en R/Ingresantes_2015_USAR_R_NUMERICOS.xlsx")
View(IngresantesN)
Ingreso<-as.data.frame(scale(IngresantesN[,3:19])  )#Normalizo datos
View(IngresantesN)
set.seed(80)    #Fijo semilla
Ingreso.km<- Ingreso.km<-kmeans(Ingreso,5)      # Aplico KMeans
names(Ingreso.km)   # Contenido del objeto     
Ingreso.km$cluster  # Asignación observaciones a cluster
Ingreso.km  #OBTENGO LOS CENTROIDES DE CADA CLUSTER X VARIABLE
```

Con lo siguiente obtuve la media de cada variable según el cluster

```
aggregate(Ingresantes[,2:3],by=list(Ingreso.km$cluster),mean)
Group.1  Carrera    Estado
1       1 13.86667 0.5666667
2       2 14.91852 0.4740741
3       3 14.61140 1.0000000
4       4 13.51429 1.0000000
5       5 13.41026 0.0000000
```

Pero no logro obtener una tabla según el cluster. Es decir obtener todos los valores de las variables de mi tabla para los individuos del cluster, por ejemplo 1

Comment: Revisa este ejemplo, en la primera seccion llamo a la taba de los clusteres: [kmeans](https://wittline.github.io/Data-Analytics-with-R/K-means/Clustering_countries_with_R.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenida!

Si no entiendo mal tu pregunta lo que buscas es agregar el número de cluster obtenido por k-means a tus datos originales. Es decir, que además de las variables haya una nueva columna que indique a que cluster pertenecen. Si no es esto ayudaría mucho que reformularas tu pregunta para aclarar lo que buscas.

No puedo reproducir tu ejemplo, porque no tengo los datos. Pero la función `kmeans()` tiene unos datos ejemplo y el procedimiento sería el mismo.

```
# reproduzco el ejemplo que viene con kmeans()

x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
x <- as.data.frame(x)

x.km <- kmeans(x, 2) #Creo los conglomerados
```

Finalmente asigno el vector con los números de cluster a la columna `cluster` del data.frame `x`

```
x$cluster <- x.km$cluster
```

Si entre un paso y el otro no reordenaste el data.frame `x` no debería haber problemas y las filas coincidir.